# why is the same code size produce different size exe file

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0

I have the code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        }
    }
}
```

that produce an exe file size 5kb.

now i just change it so all the string are different:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("3aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("4aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("5aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("6aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("7aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("8aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("9aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.WriteLine("10aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        }
    }
}
```

and now the exe file is 7kb.

Now I can guess that somewhere some feature is improving the memory use by using all the strings as only 1 string in the memory, but i don't know which...

So my question is what part is making this memory improvement?

Comment: The compiler is making making them all reference the same static string in the first example, in the second, it has to create 10 different static strings. When in doubt, look at the IL and see.

Comment: String interning babe, string interning

Comment: What would be an example of a "part" in this context? The compiler? The .NET execution engine? I'm sorry. I know I won't be able to answer the question, but I just want to understand it better.

Comment: It is not a bad question, as much as the down votes reflect. Having an attribute `[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxations(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning)]` doesn't seem to have an effect on the file size. So I am not really sure if it has anything to do with string interning.

Comment: Ah, thanks, T.S! Here's a link to the MSDN article explaining the intern pool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.intern.aspx

Comment: not quite sure why i get downvotes... but thanks to everyone that answered here and thanks to @AustinMullins for bringing the link

Comment: I believe it is "interning" in spirit, but actually performed at compile time. Consider checking IL to see if intern calls are actually present.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, IL produces the same code size for both , also interning should be related to the process memory, not its physical size, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pete and TS are correct. dotNet create a lookup table for all constant strings (Interning). In your first example all the WriteLines will look at the same internal variable, while at your second example all of them will be separate internal variables.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example all the strings are same so its taking memory refering to only one string while in your second example all the strings are different so that it takes menory 10 times it takes for the first example so memory will increase.

Comment: It's only obvious after you know about it.

Comment: i use that word frequently no offence and i removed "obvious" word